# Importing external "data.json" file into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

This may be a duplicate, but I was unable to find a previously asked question that answers mine.

I am wanting to import a .json file into my javascript like this:

```
var array = "data.json";
```

or

```
var array = $.getJson('data.json');
```

I know that both of these are wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction? **documentation** is very welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

Comment: do you mean JSON on a server?

Comment: is it case sensitive? i am using "$.getJson"

Comment: @AustinLeath Yes, it is case sensitive.

Comment: `let array = require('./data.json')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you import json file to javascript. Once the json file is imported, you can use `arr` variable which stores `json` value.

```
var arr = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "/data.json",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        arr = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: if this code works, you may consider to accept this answer. It will be helpful for others who have similar problem to looks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your JSON as a string, `JSON.parse()` will work fine. Since you are loading the json from a file, you will need to do a XMLHttpRequest to it. For example (This is w3schools.com example):

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>
<p>The content is written in JSON format, and can easily be converted into a JavaScript object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>


<p>Take a look at <a href="json_demo.txt" target="_blank">json_demo.txt</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

It will not work here as that file isn't located here. Go to this w3schools example though: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_ajax

Here is the documentation for JSON.parse(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Here's a summary:

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

Here's the example used:

```js
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.result);
// expected output: true
```

If you don't want to use XMLHttpRequests, then a JQUERY way (which I'm not sure why it isn't working for you) is  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Since it isn't working, I'd try using XMLHttpRequests

EDIT:

You could also try AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "/jsonfile.json",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thank you, i will try this, i have a file consisting of 50,000 lines, so i am storing it on my webserver and reading it on a local machine in my app.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer as it took me a while to write it (it's very long :))

Comment: @AustinLeath Also remember this answer points out documentation